# Inner Join when Duplicates Exist for Joining Variable

Tags: r, sqldf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right) nicely goes over joins in R.

And the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) on inner join is useful.

I would like to reproduce this result in base R. I don't think the following work:

```
merge(employee,department,all=T)
merge(employee,department)
```

because of the duplicates on the merging variable.

However, `sqldf` works:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from employee  inner join department ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID")
```

My questions are:

1. Does this mean that merge does not perform an inner join here.
2. How can I accomplish this join in base R.

Here are two data.frames to work with from the website and example above.

```
employee <- structure(list(LastName = c("Rafferty ", "Jones", "Steinberg", 
"Robinson", "Smith", "John"), DepartmentID = c("31", "33", "33", 
"34", " 34", " .")), .Names = c("LastName", "DepartmentID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

department <- structure(list(DepartmentID = c(31L, 33L, 34L, 35L), DepartmentName =    structure(c(4L,2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Clerical", "Engineering", "Marketing", "Sales"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DepartmentID", "DepartmentName"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Your use of `merge` doesn't match the description of how to do an inner join at the question you link to.

Comment: The sqldf output matches the example from the link. Is there a way to do this with merge? I've read in a couple of places that merge is an inner join so I'm also trying to understand the definition better. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, compare your code, `merge(employee,department,all = T)` with the instructions for doing an inner join at the question you link to above. You are not doing it as the accepted answer there instructs you to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julieth,

Please see if this works for you. I inspected the structure of the data structures to see why the results were not what was intended.

```
str(department)
str(employee)
employee$DepartmentID <- as.numeric(employee$DepartmentID)
merge(employee,department)
```

Comment: `all.x = T` does not specify an inner join. As clearly described in the question the OP themselves link to, this will produce a left outer join. (But you're right, the other problem was that one of the ID columns was characters.)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I messed that one up. As Joran notes, the structures I used were not matched. Not a good showing for my first question. :)